# jQuery and/or HTML5 video player with advanced functionalities

Tags: jquery, video, html5-video

I am looking for a jQuery (flash fall back) and/or HTML 5 solution to play video with playing backward, forward, slow motion withadaptable speed functionalities. I'd like to new a maximum information about the video currently played like a current frame information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to go with [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) although no negative `playbackRate` is possible on several browsers at the moment but I essentially needed the video to be played on iPad and this really does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/demos/index.html) jQuery based plugin. This might help you.

Comment: I've seen this one and it's one option indeed. I'm still looking for other options as I'm not totally satisfied with the backward x2 on their slow motion demo page.